# Set size issues with Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a very simple GUI panel using Swing.

Here is my code:

```
    JPanel bigBlindSelectionPanel = new JPanel();
    bigBlindSelectionPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    bigBlindSelectionPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    JList bigBlindList = new JList<String>(model);

    // Code to fill the list

    JLabel bigBlindAddLabel = new JLabel("Add big blind numbers to queries");
    bigBlindAddLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    JScrollPane bigBlindScrollPanel = new JScrollPane(bigBlindList);
    //bigBlindScrollPanel.setSize(0, 80);
    bigBlindScrollPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    JButton bigBlindAddButton = new JButton("Add");
    bigBlindAddButton.addActionListener(this);
    //bigBlindAddButton.setSize(0, 20);
    bigBlindAddButton.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    bigBlindSelectionPanel.add(bigBlindAddLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    bigBlindSelectionPanel.add(bigBlindScrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    bigBlindSelectionPanel.add(bigBlindAddButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(bigBlindSelectionPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

This is the result.

I have the following questions:

1. How do I change the size of the button and the scroll panels? The set size operations (commented in the code above) did not produce any results.
2. How do I display the frame without assigning it a size with a setSize() call? If I don't call the setSize method with a heigth and width, nothing is displayed. I am asking because I have read that I should not be using sizes if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of the JList can be controlled by using:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
```

The scrollbars will then appear or disappear as required based on the data in the model.

The button fills the width of the frame because that is the rule of the BorderLayout. If you don't want the button to fill the width then you can wrap it in a JPanel. By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which repects the size of any component added to it:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add(button);
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

> How do I display the frame without assigning it a size

You don't need the setSize() method. The `pack()` method will display the components at their preferred sizes.

Also, you don't need to specify Borders for all the components. You can create a gap between components when you create the BorderLayout:

```
bigBlindSelectionPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
```

Then you can just add a Border to the panel for the right/left edges.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! The list's visible rows, the button wrapped in a JPanel worked very well. However, if I remove the setSize() method, the frame shows an empty panel (just the title bar). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BenoitGoderre, You need to do the `pack()` AFTER you add the components to the frame otherwise the pack() is done on an empty frame. So the pack() should be done before the `setVisible(true)`.